# How can I prevent an event from firing until someone has actually stopped re-sizing the window?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When someone continuously drags a window around, resizing it (by the corner for example) and until they stop(let go of mouse button), that's when the function should fire.

I tried this, I noticed that the setTimeout always fires every time that you keep dragging the window(without letting go), I had hoped that the reset would work, but it's not working at the moment.

```
<script>

            var $window = $(window),
                timer   = 0;



            $window.resize(function() {

                // reset timer
                timer = 50;

                setTimeout(function() {

                    alert('client has stopped re-sizing the window');

                }, timer);

            });

        </script>
```

I would have thought that this makes sense as you continuously drag the window around, the setTimeout event keeps firing multiple times until you let go, it may have fired a hundred times(have to click a lot)... I only want it to fire when the person finally lets go, regardless of how long they've been dragging the window around changing its size.

Comment: I'm sure one of the other posts will have it, but what you are looking for is David Walsh's debounce explanation https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

Comment: @JonSG sorry I actually use throttle/debounce already on other stuff, that's not what I was looking for here. I need the start/stop points which I don't know how far apart that might be. The throttle/debounce if I understand correctly works on a pre-defined interval, but I did not specify that, it occurred to me later today about also using debounce/throttle to limit the times resize fired.

Comment: I don't think you can work on the assumption that a resize operation can be normalized into a single start/stop event because both in terms of user activity and browser mechanics it will always be a stream of events. If you are trying to avoid intermittent layout redraws you will come unstuck if the user starts residing immediately after you think they've stopped...

Answer (score 1):

You could use lodash's debounce function which is precisely for limiting the number of events acted upon https://lodash.com/docs#debounce , from their example:

```
jQuery(window).on('resize', _.debounce(calculateLayout, 150));
```

you can import it as a standalone npm module if you don't want the lodash library https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.debounce

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on throttle/debounce, I actually already use these for scroll-triggered events. The problem here is that I don't know how long the user might be dragging the window for. Although I will still implement the debounce, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Answer at http://alvarotrigo.com/blog/firing-resize-event-only-once-when-resizing-is-finished/.

```js
var resizeTimer;

$(window).on('resize', function(e) {

  clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
  resizeTimer = setTimeout(function() {

    alert('client has stopped re-sizing the window');

  }, 250);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ah nice I came across that clearTimeout as well, call back. Thanks this might be just what I needed. Not sure if throttle/debounce is redundant but I'll try to implement both.

Comment: Out of curiosity is that e/event necessary?

Comment: This seems to be working great, thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't actually work, I know it seems insane, but it works up to 250ms, but if you keep dragging/resizing around for a longer period that that, you'll see that the alert fires numerous times. I know it seems insane to even care about the very small chance that someone would want to drag a window around re-scaling it randomly to try and break it. For my particular application, this would break my application. So I'll have to find another way, this is a very widely accepted response, however I think it doesn't take into account the possibility of a very long re-scale time.

Comment: I think I'll add a timer that if the person still hasn't let go of the browser say in 240ms, add another 250ms, to the count down.